# Start Win32 dialog from Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, wrapper

I need some help with Win32. I`m working in VS2015.

my win32 dialog class:

```
class AddProcedureType
{
public:
    AddProcedureType();
    ~AddProcedureType();
    static BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

private:
    HWND hDialog;
    static AddProcedureType *ptr;
    void Cls_OnClose(HWND hwnd);
    BOOL Cls_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam);
    void Cls_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify);
};
```

And I want to call that window from Qt Application:

```
void getAddProcedureTypeDialog()
{
    AddProcedureType dlg;
    HINSTANCE h = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    DialogBox(h, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, dlg.DlgProc);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    getAddProcedureTypeDialog();
}
```

But when I ran program it shows only Qt App without win32 dialog.

P.S. I know about Qt Dialogs, but in this case I need Win32 dialog.

Comment: And the dialog as separate window run without any problems. I dont know how exactly I need to call it.

Comment: The `DialogBox()` call might be failing. Check its return value and error code.

Comment: Try to run it in separated thread. Btw, what is `dlg.DlgProc`? I think that it's  a wrong pointer to static function.

Comment: Are you passing the correct module handle (the one, that implements the dialog procedure and contains the dialog resources)? Creating an un-owned dialog box is also questionable. It may show up behind your Qt windows. @SaZ: Why would spreading a UI across threads help? And btw., `dlg.DlgProc` is fine. You can access static class members in C++ using the same syntax for accessing instance members.

Comment: Because `::DialogBox` has internal WinAPI-only event loop and it may broke Qt event loop.

Comment: andlabs, DialogBox() return -1 code.

Comment: @SaZ: A dialog box runs its very own internal modal loop. Qt doesn't even receive those messages. No chance for Qt to break anything. Spreading a window hierarchy across threads, on the other hand, is a guaranteed recipe for disaster.

Comment: @IInspectable i'm not so sure, because DialogBox event loop may catch some global messages. Spreading a window hierarchy across threads is a good solution to combine Qt + native. I did such things a lot of time.

Comment: @SaZ: The modal dialog loop doesn't just *"catch"* messages. It also *dispatches* them as appropriate. And no, it is not ever a good idea to spread window **hierarchies** across threads. Qt allows you to, but has **zero** provisioning to deal with the consequences. It appears to work, often enough for you to conclude correctness. Rest assured, though, that it doesn't. Stop using a pointing device, start using the keyboard, and you'll witness all the breakage that is Qt.

Comment: trouble was that I need include resource.rc file to Qt project. Thanks for all.